# CUDA device functors factory

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, factory, functor

Let say there is a C++ functor:

```
class Dummy
{
public:
    int operator() (const int a, const int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

This functor doesn't use any function that can't execute on GPU but it can't be called from CUDA kernel cause there is no __device__ declaration in front of operator(). I would like to create factory class that converts such functors to device compatible functors that can be called within CUDA kernel. For example:

```
Dummy d;
auto cuda_d = CudaFunctorFactory.get(d);
```

Can this be accomplished in any way? Feel free to add some constraints as long as it can be accomplished...

Comment: You could compile `Dummy` to LLVM byte code and then turn the bytecode into PTX using NVVM at runtime.

Comment: I understand you for Dummy compilation, but turning LLVM byte code to PTX step is not clear to me. Could you please tell me more how it can be done? And thanks very much for providing possible solution which is not NO!

Comment: [This page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-llvm-compiler) should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

The one word answer is no, this isn't possible.

There is no getting around the fact that in the CUDA compilation model, any method code contained in a class or structure which will execute on the GPU must be statically declared and defined at compile time. Somewhere in that code, there has to be a `__device__` function available during compilation, otherwise the compilation fails.  That is a completely non-negotiable cornerstone of CUDA as it exists today.

A factory design pattern can't sidestep that requirement. Further, I don't think it is possible to implement a factory for GPU instances in host code because there still isn't any way of directly accessing `__device__` function pointers from the host, and no way of directly instantiating a GPU class from the host because the constructor must execute on the GPU. At the moment, the only program units which the host can run on the GPU are `__global__` functions (ie. kernels), and these cannot be contained within classes. In CUDA, GPU classes passed by argument must be concretely defined, virtual methods aren't supported (and there is not RTTI). That eliminates all the paths I can think of to implement a factory in CUDA C++ for the GPU.

In summary, I don't see any way to make magic that can convert host code to device code at runtime.

Comment: Ok factory pattern will not save me, but see Jared Hoberock's comment on my question. He is providing some kind of solution, would you know anything about that path?

Comment: @Ognjen: He is telling you to build your own JIT solution using a C++ front end and LLVM and the CUDA driver API. That is something you are going to have to work out on your own.